# Accept Nested Attributes not working as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-attributes

So I have an entity form that accepts nested attributes for another entity. This renders perfectly fine. However, the nested form is not functioning as I would like it to. See below:

```
<table class="datagrid">
  <thead class="datagrid">
        <th width="300" align="left">&nbsp;Item</th>
        <% unless current_user.is_partner? %>
            <th width="100">&nbsp;Location</th>
        <% end %>
        <th>&nbsp;Amount Requested</th>
        <th>&nbsp;Amount Checked Out</th>
  </thead>

    <% session[:clicked_request].items.each do |item| %>  
      <tr class="<%= cycle('dg_list_line_odd', 'dg_list_line_even') %>">  
        <td>&nbsp;<%= link_to "#{item.name}", item_path(item) %></td>  
            <% unless current_user.is_partner? %>
            <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;<%= item.location.name %></td>
            <% end %>
            <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<%= item.requested %></td>
            <td><%= f.text_field :amount, :value => item.requested, :size => 1 %></td>
      </tr>  
    <% end %>
</table>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
```

As you can see there is an "each" loop here, that allows for the display, and hopefully the creation, of multiple items. However, when I press the submit button, regardless of how many items are present, only one of them is created.

Your suggestions are much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

That's not how you render forms with `accepts_nested_attributes`

Assuming `f` is a form builder bound to the parent object, you need to do something like

```
<%= f.fields_for :items do |item_form| %>
  <%= item_form.text_field :amount
<% end %>
```

The block will be executed once for each item in the collection. In addition, `item_form` is setup with the right prefix for the controller side to work properly.

Comment: You are almost correct expect for the fact that `accepts_nested_attributes` look the writer attributes with `_attributes` so the above form has to build a hash which has a key called `items_attributes` which required setting `name` for the above form explicitly cuz I guess in the above case it create a hash of `items`   . you can check the same in `http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html`

Comment: If you're doing it right, fields_for will set the name for you

Comment: Oops, i had written form_for instead of fields for

Comment: I never encountered it always set the name as the object name "items" in the above case and not "items_attributes" as `accepts_nested_attributes_for` want it . Perhap i will test again

Comment: make sure you do f.fields_for_and not fields_for

Comment: are you sure it does coz as I tested I'm quite sure it doesnt 'f' will only wrap it the `object` in the main hash something like `main[items][]` and something like `main[items_attributes][]` please check and let me know

Comment: I checked it and then confronted you probably there is something that either of us is missing over here thanks anyway